# location not detecting using gwt map api

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I am using a GWT web-based application which is using map API for searching places, mapshare, poi etc.
actually when I am  loading map into microsoft edge browser it is asking location access of user and if I don't allow and search anything into map then it is zooming into arctic ocean but pointing to correct location for the first time, and it is behaving properly in other browser like chrome, firefox etc.
and I am not able to debug also the entire project using eclipse. Every time I have to use maven build command to launch the application locally.